# facebook login not working for the first time in ios

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to integrate Facebook Login in my Sencha application.
The problem is when I click on facebook login button which calls the `promptLogin()` function of Facebook, facebook login screen is not popping up but at the same time when I pause the application and resume back to the same, it pops up. I am using Facebook-cordova-plugin
Can anybody help me regarding this?